# What is the path of the nuget package i just installed

Tags: powershell, nuget

Given I have just installed the most recent version of a package using nuget (using powershell), outside of a solution or project folder e.g. `PS> nuget install octopustools` then a directory is created below the current folder, in this case `\OctopusTools.4.22.1`.

I want to access the exe inside the package that has relative path `\OctopusTools.4.22.1\tools\octo.exe`. However I want an easy way to know the path in my script because the version number can change based on releases.

Is there easy way to get nuget to tell me the name of the folder it has just installed to, i.e. OctopusTools.4.22.1?

I want to avoid guessing the path based on recursivly scanning folders or hardcoding the version number if possible. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference#install) do not seem to offer anything obvious?

Comment: .NET Framework or Core (they put NuGet derived content in different places)?

Comment: Actually kind of neither (and both!). Assume the latests version of nuget.exe is installed on the PATH and I just run `nuget install octopustools`

Comment: Might do nothing at all if the project uses `PackageReference` (standard for .net core projects and opt-in for .net framework) and it already is in the global packages cache which can be defined by an NuGet.Config in the path. So it really depends on your exact setup and what you are trying to do.

Comment: As I mention in the question, I'm running this command outside of a solution so it just installs to a child folder of the current directory.

Comment: You could use the -ExcludeVersion command line argument. If you run `nuget install octopustools -ExcludeVersion` then the version folder will not be created and instead you could access octo.exe just using `OctopusTools\tools\octo.exe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to @[Matt Ward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/268874/matt-ward) whose comment solved it - just use ExcludeVersion and then the path to the installed exe is guaranteed, even when a different version is installed.

To get this to work I had to update the version of nuget installed as older versions do not support this flag. (update is easy if using chocolatey: `choco upgrade nuget.commandline -y`

And then to get to octo.exe (and in this example call help) just do this:

```
PS> nuget install OctopusTools --ExcludeVersion
PS> OctopusTools\tools\octo.exe help
```

Comment: this does not work for global packages in `nuget locals global-packages -list` folder, any installation there will ignore -ExcludeVersion parameter

Answer (score 1):

If using PowerShell `Install-Package` cmdlet you can get the newly installed Octopus Tools folder and add it to the path (which is why I imagine you want to know where it is installed) as follows:

```
PS>Install-Package -Name OctopusTools -Force
PS>$octoPath = (Get-Item((Get-Package -Name OctopusTools).Source)).DirectoryName +"\tools"
PS>$octoPath
PS>$env:Path += $env:Path + $octoPath
```